# Perforce reconcile offline work doesn't notice the changes

Tags: perforce

So, I created a new file and copied it over the one in the workspace. Then I selected "reconcile offline work" from the context menu of the directory containing the file, after I've updated the directory and made sure the workspace has the new version of the file - but Perforce says that no files have changed.

There is one more weirdness in this: Despite having the latest version of the program, both the `p4` and `p4v` clients, perhaps, because of the server version, I don't have `reconcile` command available (I don't know what version is the server, and don't know how to find it out).

So, it would help if you could tell how to do the same thing as `reconcile`, while not having this command (it seems to be a newish addition, but I cannot imagine a workflow that doesn't require you to use it, or something that does the same thing). The VCS is practically useless if it cannot figure out on its own what files had changed since the last version...

Comment: Type `p4 info` at the command line to display your server version.  The reconcile command requires client _and server_ version [2012.1 or higher](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/relnotes.txt).

Answer (score 2):

If your server is older, and doesn't support reconcile, there are other ways to accomplish these tasks. Start here for all the details: http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Working-Disconnected-From-The-Perforce-Server

Answer (score 0):

If you added a file to Perforce and copied it to another workspace you will need "p4 sync -k //depot/path/to/file" to reflect the change.